# Java for loop that includes multiple conditions and increments multiple integers

Tags: java, loops, syntax, nested-loops

I am working on a program that extracts pixels from images using the Color method in Java. That's not that relevant however.

I need to increment the X and Y variables up to their image width and height respectively. I have tried nesting the for loops but it only triggers the other one as soon as the condition on the other one is met.

CODE

```
    for (int x = 0; x<ScreenWidth; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y<ScreenHeight; y++)
        {

        Color c = new Color(DesktopCapture.getRGB(x,y));
        int r = c.getRed();
        int g = c.getGreen();
        int b = c.getBlue();
        System.out.println("Colour at location of screen is " + r + " " + g + " " + b + " Position is " + x + " " + y);

        Thread.sleep(40);
```

OUTPUT

```
Colour at location of screen is 151 184 216 Position is 0 0
Colour at location of screen is 151 186 218 Position is 0 1
Colour at location of screen is 151 188 220 Position is 0 2
Colour at location of screen is 151 190 222 Position is 0 3
Colour at location of screen is 152 192 224 Position is 0 4
Colour at location of screen is 152 194 226 Position is 0 5
Colour at location of screen is 152 195 227 Position is 0 6
Colour at location of screen is 153 196 228 Position is 0 7
Colour at location of screen is 153 197 229 Position is 0 8
Colour at location of screen is 154 197 229 Position is 0 9
Colour at location of screen is 154 196 228 Position is 0 10
Colour at location of screen is 154 195 227 Position is 0 11
Colour at location of screen is 154 194 225 Position is 0 12
Colour at location of screen is 154 192 223 Position is 0 13
Colour at location of screen is 154 190 221 Position is 0 14
Colour at location of screen is 154 188 219 Position is 0 15
Colour at location of screen is 153 186 216 Position is 0 16
Colour at location of screen is 152 184 214 Position is 0 17
Colour at location of screen is 152 182 212 Position is 0 18
Colour at location of screen is 153 181 210 Position is 0 19
Colour at location of screen is 210 222 234 Position is 0 20
```

Comment: That appears to be working as expected - it will do all the `y` values for `x = 0`, then `x = 1`, and so on and so forth. What exactly do you perceive as "wrong" about it?

Comment: Can you explain more what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl I want a for loop that increments both x and y with their own conditions rather then doing each variable individually. Thanks for asking,

Comment: ...but it is incrementing them both? Bear in mind a full cycle of y values for `x = 0` has to elapse before `x` can increment as it is the outer loop's variable. What are the values of `ScreenWidth` and `ScreenHeight`?

Comment: @user2419270 What do you mean by `increments both x and y with their own conditions`. Do you want to use something like this `for (int i = 0, j = 0; (i < 5 || j < 5); i++, j++) {`

Comment: @Smit Looks about right. Will try that.

Comment: @Smit I was wondering that myself, but then that wouldnt cover all pixels from the image but rather a diagonal line across it, which didnt make much sense to me.

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl Even I am not sure what OP wants. I am still trying to understand OPs requirements and that's the reason I put that code piece as comment.

Comment: @Smit Indeed. OP, do you think you could try and elaborate on what you are actually trying to achieve with this function? We need a bit more context.

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl Sure. Ill think of a better way to word this and reply back.

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl Meh. I give up for now. Will think of other ways to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

The run time complexity of your solution is going to be horrible: O(N^2). You might solve this recursively by doing something like:

```
int height = 0;
int width = 0;

public void returnPixels(int height, int width)
     Color c = new Color(DesktopCapture.getRGB(width,height));
        int r = c.getRed();
        int g = c.getGreen();
        int b = c.getBlue();
        System.out.println("Colour at location of screen is " + r + " " + g + " " + b + " Position is " + x + " " + y);
      if(height < screenHeight){
        if(width < screenwidth){
           width++;
           returnPixels(height, width);
        } else if(width > screenWidth){
          width=0;
          height++;
          returnPixels(height, width);
          }
       }
    }
```

Or something similar. This will read each line, then when it gets to the end, it moves to the next height line